# Why is not possible to make serology exam in animal's blood with hemolysis?

Tags: cats

I am not from the medical area but I am struggling with a trouble with my pets and it seems that no veterinary here in my city know how to explain this to me. I have two cats and I need to make an internacional travel with them. To accomplish this, I need to make serology exam on them. But, something is happening with the blood because is happening hemolysis after taking it off.

Though I have made some researchs about why hemolysis happens and none of them convince me at all, my question is: why serology can not be made with a tiny hemolisys in blood? I have took the blood of my cat three times to prove she does not have anger disease and lab (the unique in Brazil which is allowed to make this) is saying they cannot make the exame because the blood had a really really tiny hemolysis. Is this truth or it is only burocracy? (I already have heard this theory)

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

Some lab machines are very sensitive and will be inaccurate if the sample is hemolyzed. To reduce the chance of hemolysis they need to use a larger gauge (23G-22G) needle and obtain the sample from her jugular vein. This location gets a very large, clean sample at once compared to her cephalic/saphenous veins.

I hope they are not charging you for each visit, we've done rabies (I assume it's comparable to anger disease) titres with no issues like that. Though in Canada our lab equipment might be more advanced than Brazil.